# photoshop - how to drag one layer INTO another layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I googled this and couldn't find it and i forgot how to do it. I want to drag a layer3 inside of layer2, i forgot the shortcut key, in the layers pallet you grab 1 layer and hold some key and drag the layer on top of the one you want to place it inside of... GRR, thank you!

Comment: This is nonsense. Why on earth would you want to place a layer "inside" another layer. It makes no sense at all. You're talking about MERGING layers. Either that or you wish to make a group of layers (CTRL - G). Or maybe you're getting confused about Clipping Masks? (CTRL + ALT + G) Whatever it is, you cannot place a layer "inside" an existing layer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to "merge" the layers (right-click). You can drag layers into layer groups if you need to group them. Then you can drag the entire group around the page.

I personally have never dragged a layer onto another layer. I merge them.

Comment: not merge, it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

i was suffering with the same problem, and i just figured it out. you click on the layer below the layer you want inside. now put the cursor right in the middle of the two layers. click alt, you will see a a sign which has one black and one white circle in it. and just click. the layer will be inside/

Comment: That isn't "inside" a layer, it's creating a Clipping Mask (CTRL + ALT + G).